# How to detect when a phone call is triggered when the application is up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My application is a coupon shopping,users will download the coupons in phone and when completed they will be directed for the automatic cash payment.
If a user downloads 5 coupons and inbetween gets a call as it is iOS4 it goes to background.
So when we press the home button also the application goes to background by this behaviour.I have save few data and restore the coupons when the user quits the application by homebutton.
But in iOS 4 behaviour homebutton press and phone call interruptions shows the same behaviour and calls the same functions,how i could differentiate between the 2.
Please this is a tedious function,please help me.......

Answer (score 2):

**Without multi-tasking:** For applications that do not support background execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, `applicationWillTerminate:` method is always called when the user quits the application. **For applications that support background execution, this method is generally not called** when the user quits the application because the application simply moves to the background in that case.

**With multi-tasking:** You can implement `applicationWillResignActive:`delegate method in your app delegate, which gets called during *temporary interruptions (such as an `incoming phone call` or `SMS message`) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.*

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    flag = YES;
    [self doCleanUp];
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    if (!flag) [self doCleanUp];
}
```

Comment: i want to get the difference between quitting by user and call interruptions.I have to write different functions to be carried out during these 2 states but how to identify which one.

Comment: sorry for my awkward questions but i could not understand it,applicationwillResignActive is called for both quitting by homebutton and by phone call interruptions.How to detect homebutton press or click

Comment: In my application when i quit the applicationwillterminate is never called when i press home button,on by deleting it from the tray it is called.The logic is fine but how could i trigger the terminate function..........pls make it clear

Comment: You don't have to call any method. If the device supports multi-tasking then `applicationWillResignActive:` method will be called, else `applicationWillTerminate:` method will be called

Answer (score 1):

iOS will not tell an app what caused an interruption such as a phone call, an SMS message, or a press of the home button. This is a deliberate design decision by Apple.  Apple expects apps to be designed to exhibit the same behavior no matter what caused the interruption.

Comment: How to change this logic according to my application mentioned above